# About Wireless Power Transfer

Tags: transformer, wireless

I want to ask some questions
Here is my original circuit. There is a diff. pair VCO and a LC tank in Tx side. If  the Tx/Rx side does not couple with each other, I evaluate the resonant frequency will be 1/2pi(LC)^0.5=17.6MHz,But when I couple with k(coupling factor)=0.7 in Rx side ,the oscillation frequency will be increase to 32.84 MHz ,I want to ask why can it do that or if the is some reference to check?[image]

[image]

Comment: How does the Tx change VCO?

Comment: You mean Tx frequency change? About 15.24MHz 

Comment: What is the resonant frequency of the RX circuit  when uncoupled? (Presumably the same as the TX circuit )